# SQL Server is unavailable when running unit test case from Jenkins workspace

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, jenkins, visual-studio-2017

I am running some SQL Server unit test cases from VS 2017(which are running fine), but when i run the same test cases from Jenkins they end up throwing error "Server is unavailable".

Even if I am opening the solution from Jenkins work space in VS 2017 and 
running the tests they end up throwing the same error.

Building and testing the code in VS2017 from **E:\somedir\mytest.sln** runs fine but running the same mytest.sln from **C:\ProgramFiles\Jenkins\Workspace\test\mytest.sln** ends up throwing error **Server is unavailable**

Why am I getting this error when VS 2017 and Jenkins are installed on the same server, it's just the directories are different.

**NOTE:** I have already checked the network, user permissions and passwords but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related to a whitespace in your path?

Typically it is:

```
C:\Program Files\Jenkins\Workspace
```

Comment: Got the solution it was due to the hostname\instanceName, VSTest was unable to understand the connection string name.